# Is it possible to make my tumblr theme display default photoset or custom slider depending on tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, tumblr

I'm currently using a custom Slider for my photoset posts on tumblr (http://woothemes.com/flexslider)

I wanted to know if its possible to make my theme display the default tumblr photoset (instead of the custom slider) when a post is tagged as #set. I wouldn't mind if I also had to tag the photoset posts that I want to display using the custom Slider to make it work.

It seems pretty complicated for me but maybe there's a solution using javascript.

Thank you

---

**Update:** I spent some time on it and I managed to solve this without any javascript (it was simpler than I thought it would be)

> .post .photo-slideshow {display: none;}
>
> .post.set .flexslider {display: none;}
>
> .post.set .photo-slideshow {display: block!important;}

I basically put together in the `{block:Photoset}...{/block:Photoset}` tag. both the flexslider code and [Pixel Union's custom photoset](https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset) code and used the css above to hide the slider when the photoset is tagged as #set.

I had to use the custom photoset script because it wouldn't work with tumblr's default photoset iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying both and hiding one, seems a little hacky. Why not use the tag / correct selector to create either a `slider` or `photoset`?

**HTML**

```
/* Default - slider */
<div class="post">
  <ul class="photoset">...</ul>
</div>

/* Tagged `set` - photoset */
<div class="post set">
  <ul class="photoset">...</ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Default, so create a slider.
$('.post:not(.set)').find('.photoset').pxuPhotoset({ ... });

// Tagged `set`, so create a photoset.
$('.post.set').find('.photoset').pxuPhotoset({ ... });
```